# How do I add install command line arguments to prerequisites (like .NET Framework or SQL Server Express) in Visual Studio 2015 Setup Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, bootstrapper, sql-server-2012-express

I'm trying to add specific command line install arguments to a prerequisite (SQL Server 2012 Express) for a Windows Setup Project in Visual Studio 2015.

I've selected "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application" and downloaded and placed the required installers in their respective bootstrap folders (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\...`) and I modified the `package.xml` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2012\en` to include my specific changes to `<Command Arguments="my specific stuff" />`

This builds fine and when I go to test the install it failed during the SQL Server 2012 Express install.

The install.log notes:

```
Installing using command 'C:\Users\ljhersma\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDFB27.tmp\SqlExpress2012\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE' and parameters 'my specific stuff'
Process exited with code -2054422506
Status of package 'SQL Server 2012 Express' after install is 'InstallFailed'
```

So the fact that the install.log picked up my specific commands proves that the modification of `packages.xml` worked, but I'm not sure why its actually failing.

Let me know if you need any more information!

Answer (score 0):

So, my original command contained `/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Users"`, but I noticed [this guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.110).aspx) saying that all single value parameters must not be in quotes.  Simply removing the quotes solved the issue.